# Uber API personal access token is invalid and cannot be tested

Tags: python, uber-api

```
from uber_rides.session import Session
from uber_rides.client import UberRidesClient

session = Session(server_token='server_token')
client = UberRidesClient(session)
response = client.get_products(37.77, -122.41)
products = response.json.get('products')
```

After running
uber_rides.errors.ClientError: 401: Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided.

Comment: So… how did you get the token? How do you know it's valid (which apparently it isn't)?

Comment: Obtained from the test method given by the Uber application